# Python NameError: name 'lix' is not defined

Tags: python

```
dictx1 = {}
dictx2 = {'C':['D','A'],'sXZ':['W','L']}
dictx3 = {'C':['3','4'],'sXZ':['3KL','E','S']}
```

I want to merge dictx2 and dictx3 to dictx1 and get the output as "{'C': ['D', 'A','3','4'], 'sXZ': ['W', '3KL', 'L', 'E','S']}"

I wrote below code

```
dictx1 = {}
dictx1 = dictx2.copy()
ds= [dictx1, dictx3]
for i in dictx2.keys():
    dictx1[i] = list(lix[i][x] for x in range(len(lix[i]) for lix in ds)
```

Error:
    dictx1[i] = list(lix[i][x] for x in range(len(lix[i])) for lix in ds)
NameError: name 'lix' is not defined

But it already there with the 'for lix in ds'. I can write the code as below to get the same answer. But I want to know what's wrong with the above one line for code

```
s=[]
```

for i in dictx2.keys():

```
for li in ds:
    for x in range(len(li[i])):
        s.append(li[i][x])

dictx1[i] = s

s = []
```

print (dictx1)

Comment: where are you defining `i`?

Comment: Nested generator comprehensions have the `for ... in ...`s in the other order.

Comment: joost : I corrected it in the code. One line was missing.

Answer (score 2):

```
dictx2 = {'C':['D','A'],'sXZ':['W','L']}
dictx3 = {'C':['3','4'],'sXZ':['3KL','E','S']}

for k,v in dictx2.items():
    res =  dictx3.get(k, None)
    if res == None:
        dictx3.update({k:v})
    else:
        dictx3.update({k : v + res})

print(dictx3)
```

output

```
{'C': ['D', 'A', '3', '4'], 'sXZ': ['W', 'L', '3KL', 'E', 'S']}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and add all lists in a loop:

```
from collections import defaultdict

dictx1 = defaultdict(list)
for dic in (dictx2, dictx3):
    for key, value in dic.items():
        dictx1[key].extend(value)

# result: defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'C': ['D', 'A', '3', '4'],
#                                      'sXZ': ['W', 'L', '3KL', 'E', 'S']})
```

If you don't want a `defaultdict` as the result, add `dictx1 = dict(dictx1)` to turn it into a normal dict.